# Can you open a database from inside a fragment without communicating with the parent activity?

Tags: android, database, android-fragments

Is it possible to open a database directly from inside a fragment? I've tried passing a databasehandler from my activity to the fragment and I know it works. I'm just wondering if I can do it some other way. Maybe a better way.

Answer (score 1):

you can create an instance of the Database handler in your fragment like this

```
   DatabaseHandler dbh = new DatabaseHandler(getActivity());
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd double check the specific implementation for `DatabaseHandler` but I believe any context will do so you could roll your own implementation of `Application.getInstance()` and use your application context.

This frees your code from needing to hook into any `Activity` instance.